# How to exit early in a recursive call

Tags: recursion

I have a function like this:

```
def foo(A)
    for (i=0; i<A.len; i++) {
        if (A == something)
            foo(A.next)
        else 
            # here I'd like to return A's value
            # return A.value
```

If there a way to make this work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you do:

```
def foo(A)
    for (i=0; i<A.len; i++) {
        if (A == something)
            return foo(A.next)
        else 
            return A.value
```

where `A.value` will be returned to the last of `foo(A.next)`, which will return all the way back to the first call of `foo()`.